# getKey(alias, keyPassword) returns null value for secret key when calling from separate method

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, keystore, secret-key

I am trying to retrieve a stored key in java key store. I have written the following code.

```
public class clientEncryptionUtility
{

    public static void generateKeyAndStoreOnKeyStore(String _keyStorePassword, String _keyStorePath, String _keyPassword, String keyAlias) throws Exception // take the keystore path, alias, password
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        char[] keyStorePassword = _keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
        String path = _keyStorePath;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        //load keystore
        keyStore.load(fis, keyStorePassword);
        //Loading the KeyStore object
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protectionParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword);

        //Generate the symmetric key for encryption
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

        int keyBitSize = 128;

        keyGenerator.init(keyBitSize, secureRandom);

        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();   //Secret encryption key is genereated

        //setting the password for the key stored in keystore
        System.out.println("Algorithm used to generate key : "+secretKey.getAlgorithm()); 

        char[] keyPassword = _keyPassword.toCharArray();

        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter entryPassword = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyPassword);

        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);

        keyStore.setEntry(keyAlias, secretKeyEntry, entryPassword);
        SecretKey newSecretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, keyPassword);
        String stringKey = newSecretKey.toString();
        System.out.println("The encryption key at the alias is: " + stringKey);
    }
    public static void getKeyFromKeyStore(String _keyStorePassword, String _keyStorePath, String keyAlias, String _keyPassword) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        char[] keyStorePassword = _keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
        String path = _keyStorePath;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);

        //load keystore
        keyStore.load(fis, keyStorePassword);
        char[] keyPassword = _keyPassword.toCharArray();
        SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, keyPassword);
        // Key key = keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, keyPassword);
        String stringKey = secretKey.toString();
        System.out.println("The encryption key at the alias is: " + stringKey);

    }
}
```

-If I call the generateKeyAndStoreOnKeyStore() method, and store the key and retrieve the key in the same function, the key is retrieved.

-However if I do the same from another method getKeyFromKeyStore() wherein I am just trying to retrieve the key at the alias from the keystone, I get a nullPointerException.

-Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not clear from the javadocs that you must call the [`KeyStore.store(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store-java.io.OutputStream-char:A-) method to *persist* changes to the keystore. Once `generateKeyAndStoreOnKeyStore()` exits, the `KeyStore` instance created there goes out of scope and any unsaved changes made to the keystore disappear.

Call the `KeyStore.store(...)` method after making changes.

Comment: I figured the same out, It worked after adding KeyStore.store() upon adding the secret key.